# Is my encryption example secure?

Tags: c#, security, encryption

A while ago I was developing a little encryption technique to learn more about computer security. Well, this was about 8 months ago now and I kind of never went back to it. That has changed! I'm writing a small asp.net website for my works Intranet where a login system will be needed, so I'm going to want to encrypt the passwords and store them in a database.

So, i'll run you through my notes I did a while ago with examples and I'm wondering if I could get some feedback / if what I've done is basically pointless / very insecure (Not counting the fact I'm running you through how it works...)

Moving on!

The first thing I do is break the inputted string down to each character value, so if for example the user has the password "Hello" it would be broken down as follows...

```
"H" = 104,
"E" = 101,
"L" = 108,
"L" = 108,
"O" = 111
```

The next thing I do is generate a random number, lets just say between 50 and 100 to keep things simple, then I find the nth prime number from that pseudo random number, so if the generated number was 70 it would give me `349`

The next thing I do is then add up all the decimal numbers from the converted inputted string.

`104 + 101 + 108 + 108 + 111 = 532`

Then I multiply the given number by the found nth prime number, so `532 * 349` giving me `185668`.

Then, that number is stored in the database with the hash (or whatever you call it) - nth prime number - in another column.

Comment: _"**I** was developing a little encryption technique [...] is it secure?"_ - are you a security expert? Then no.

Comment: Why not just hash and use a salt? It's easy to implement and way harder to crack.

Comment: I've never done any security at Uni but I find it interesting - best way to learn? Do it and get feedback! Well in my case anyway :) Plus, it will be pretty easy to implement - and FUN!

Comment: @JohnathanBrown the best way to learn would be to [take the Coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/course/cryptography)

Comment: @JohnathanBrown The only thing you have to learn here is *"Don't reinvent the wheel"*. Just use what's out there, people have already come up with **much** better solutions.

Comment: Also: how is this encryption? as far as I can see it's non-reversible (since there's no way to distinguish `HELLO` from `HLELO`, etc)...

Comment: Theres a whole namespace "System.Security.Cryptography" that can help you implementing en/decryption

Comment: @ircmaxell it does not have to be reversable. You just encrypt it and check if your encryption fits the one in the database. Same as normal hashing.

Comment: It doesn't need to be reversible, when the user inputs his password it grabs the salt from the database, does the same method and then compares the two values, if they're correct then the password is the same, if not then the user entered it incorrectly.

Comment: But seriously, to explain why this is or isn't a good hashing technique would be too broad for SO. It works the other way around. Educate yourself and ask a specific question, not _"Is this good?"_.

Comment: @DionV. that's hashing. Hashing is not encryption. Confusing terminology is not a good idea.

Comment: @JohnathanBrown Made me think - doesn't this mean that if my password is `HELLO`, I can also login with `HLELO`?

Comment: @DionV. Ha... Good point :') Recipe for disaster indeed!

Comment: @ircmaxell Fair enough, still my point holds.

Comment: I feel like I've just had a slap on the wrist like my Nan used to do when I was a wee nipper :') Off to the msdn developer network I go to go read up on the System.Security.Cryptography!

Comment: Once you have The nth prime number your crypto is so hackable , not a good algorithm , nice thinking , just try to think out of the box

Answer (score 4):

Is this secure? No. Does this protect the users' password? No.

It's vulnerable to rudimentary cryptanalysis. For example, with a simple SQL Injection the attacker could get both the "hash" and the prime number.

From there, the attacker could simply divide the hash by the prime and get the sum of the characters.

The interesting thing here is that while the original password is protected, collisions are not. So the attacker could generate a trivial collision and use it to log into your site.

For example, let's say after dividing the "hash" was 532. We could get that same hash by a 7 character string of repeating `>` characters (`">>>>>>>"`).

Good hash functions have 3 fundamental properties:

1. Pre-image resistance (given `h(m)` it should be hard to find `m`)
2. Second-pre-image resistance (given `m` it should be hard to find `n` such that `h(m) == h(n)`)
3. Collision Resistance (it should be difficult to find a pair of messages such that `h(m) == h(n)`.

Your given function only possibly does the first, but only in that there are so many possible permutations (collisions) that it's impossible to tell what the original was...

So definitely not.

I recommend using approved and vetted crypto, and take the [Coursera Cryptography Course](https://www.coursera.org/course/cryptography).